# Enter Cyprus with Schengen residence permit

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, long-stay-visas, chinese-citizens, cyprus

I am a Chinese Passport holder, living in China and have a valid Schengen residence permit. 
Last year, I entered Schengen areas with a valid Schengen visa. During my stay in Schengen areas, I was issued a ~2 years residence permit by one Schengen country. When I left Schengen areas, my Schengen Visa was still valid and I didn’t show the residence permit to the customs officer.
Now the Schengen visa has expired.

Can I enter Cyprus with the residence permit/card directly? Or do I have to use the residence permit to enter one Schengen country then go to Cyprus?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can enter Cyprus with your passport and *valid* EU common format residence permit issued by a Schengen member state.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states in relevant part:

> Cyprus (CY)
>
> Passport required.
>
> Document Validity:
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for a minimum of 3 months beyond the period of
>     intended stay.
>
> Visa Exemptions:
>
> - Passengers with a residence permit issued by Bulgaria, Croatia, Romania or a Schengen Member State for a maximum stay of 90 days. (SEE NOTE 66301)
> - This does not apply to nationals of Azerbaijan and Turkey.
>
>   NOTE 66301: The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.